# Is it practical to install a second water heater near my kitchen?

Tags: electrical, water-heater

My bathroom and my kitchen are very far apart in my house.
The original water heater is in the bathroom.
Is it practical to install a second water heater (small) near the kitchen so that it runs (the second) only when the first heater is not in use.

Water heaters already have the first element in priority to the second element with a relay control priority.
I would like to  instal a second relay on the second element of the first water heater to feed power to  the second heater.

My breaker panel is already full, it would allow me not to add another breaker. In addition, it would save me a long length of cable.

I have found that my hot water usage in the bathroom is greatest in the morning, and in the kitchen, at night.

Would this change be legal in Canada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US the code requires the water heater to be a safety listed device (e.g UL listed).  Modifications of the device void the safety listing. So it would not be in compliance to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about legality, but they do make under the counter on demand water heaters.